# tree partitioning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tree, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a 2d symmteric matrix "myMSTdata[][]" that represents weighted edge minimum spanning tree MST (zero if there is no direct edge) and I need to cut that MST on the edge with maximum weight such that I have two subtree partitions (part1,part2). Is there any easy or cheap way to do so? or is there any library that I can use for doing so?

Comment: I never used it, but have you taken a look at Boost::Graph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `boost::graph` library:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.html